# oracle insert into table using subquery

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-00907

I hope you are well. I need your help with the following question from kaplan trianing exam question. The query below is suppose to be the correct answer but I cannot get it to work. Could you please check and advise.

rgd's

Norman

```
SQL> EDIT
Wrote file afiedt.buf



INSERT INTO
(SELECT PHYSICIAN_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, LICENSE_NO, HIRE_DATE
FROM PHYSICIAN
WITH CHECK OPTION
WHERE LICENSE_NO BETWEEN 1 AND 200)
VALUES (PHY_NUM_SEQ.NEXTVAL, '&LNAME', '&FNAME', &LNO, SYSDATE)

SQL> /
**Enter value for lname: BARRETT

Enter value for fname: NORMAN

Enter value for lno: 1**

old   6: VALUES (PHY_NUM_SEQ.NEXTVAL, '&LNAME', '&FNAME', &LNO, SYSDATE)
new   6: VALUES (PHY_NUM_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BARRETT', 'NORMAN', 1, SYSDATE)
WHERE LICENSE_NO BETWEEN 1 AND 200)

*

> **ERROR at line 5: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**



SQL> `SELECT PHY_NUM_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;`



   NEXTVAL
----------
         1



SQL> DESC PHYSICIAN


Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PHYSICIAN_ID                              NOT NULL NUMBER
 LAST_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 FIRST_NAME                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
 LICENSE_NO                                NOT NULL NUMBER(7)
 HIRE_DATE                                          DATE


SQL>
```

Comment: You are not specifying a table name for the insert. It should be `insert into target_table (column_1, column_2, ...) select ... from ...` (no `values` clause!)

Answer (score 1):

There's `WITH CHECK OPTION` line which causes the error

> *ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis*

inside your `SELECT` statement.

It's enough to remove that line.

Comment: Cheers guys you are correct the WITH CHECK OPTION should be below the WHERE clause. Working now